# Can't convert String to integer or undefined method nil for []

Tags: httparty

Using Httparty, I get the following response

```
@parsed_reponse = > {"items" => {"@no" => "1", "@type" => "book", "@category" => "GENERAL" }}
```

when i use the following code to access `@no`, I am getting the 
following error: "Can't convert String into Integer"

```
r = @response.parsed_response["items"]["@no"]
```

Can anyone help on this? I do get "Can't convert String into Integer"
or "Undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"

Can anyone explain this with an example?

Answer (score 0):

I am no HTTParty expert but here is an example of what I do to iterate through all the data in a response:

```
class Items
  include HTTParty
  default_params :output => 'xml'
  format :xml
  base_uri '<base_uri>'
end

xml =  Items.get('<xmlFile>')

xml["items"].each do |item|
  puts Integer(item['@no'])
end
```